# How to force update of css files in development with bundling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

As I understand it, MVC bundling and minification will automatically update a version parameter when any file in the bundle changes to ensure the browser gets the latest files when they change.

However, in development it is not actually bundling but rather serving up the files as is. So when I switch between branches of a project I'm working on sometimes I have to refresh the cache on my browser as it has the version from the previous branch still cached.

If I weren't using bundling this would be an easy issue to resolve as I would just add my own version parameter. However, if I try to add a version number in the path (like so: `.Include("~/Scripts/Site.css?v=123")` then I get an error.

I've seen some examples that use a `{version}` keyword in the path when retrieving from a CDN. Is there some way to use this when serving our own local css files? I'm asking this question because I half way expect someone might answer "oh, just use the `{version}` keyword" but I want to make it clear that if that's the answer then I need a little more specific detail on exactly how to implement that solution. Or is there some alternative solution?